# Amazon S3: move files out of a bucket and into Glacier

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-glacier

I have an S3 bucket (call it `main_bucket`) to which various TIFF files are uploaded. On upload to `main_bucket`, a Lambda function is triggered which converts the TIFF to a JPEG and also stores the JPEG in the bucket. I would like to then store the TIFF in Glacier *and remove it from `main_bucket`*, and I am not sure how to do this.

I can, of course, create a second bucket (call it `archive`), set the lifecycle on `archive` so that it stores all contents in the Glacier storage class, and set lifecycle rules on `main_bucket` so that all TIFF files in `main_bucket` are copied to `archive`. This will ensure that a copy of an uploaded TIFF ends up in `archive`, and since all things in `archive` are in the Glacier storage class, this means that all TIFFs end up in Glacier, which is what I want. **But**: this approach also keeps a copy of each TIFF in `main_bucket`, which I *don't* want. I can delete the TIFFs from `main_bucket`, but I don't know when to do that; I don't believe there's an event corresponding to the copy to `archive` being completed. Is there some way to do what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving objects to the `Glacier` or `Glacier Deep Archive` storage class is an excellent way to archive objects that are rarely (potentially *never*) accessed.

It appears that your scenario is:

- TIFF is uploaded to **Bucket-A**
- This triggers an AWS Lambda function that converts the TIFF to a JPG and stores it in the **same bucket**
- You would then like the TIFF moved to a **Bucket-B** and moved into a Glacier storage class

**Option 1: Swap bucket order**

- Have the TIFF uploaded to **Bucket-B**
- This then triggers the Lambda function that stores the JPG in **Bucket-A** (a different bucket!)
- Add a **Lifecycle rule** to Bucket-B that archives the TIFFs after a certain period

The beauty of this option is that no objects need to be moved. Objects are always created in the bucket where they are desired.

**Option 2: Move the object as part of the Lambda function**

- After the Lambda function creates the JPG in **Bucket-A**, it should also:
- Copy the TIFF to **Bucket-B**
- Delete the TIFF from **Bucket-A**
- Add a **Lifecycle rule** to Bucket-B that archives the TIFFs after a certain period